# Rails 3 rake db:migrate fails with a 'rake aborted! can't convert SQLite3::Statement into Array'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, dbmigrate

I was working through Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial when I experienced an error while trying to migrate my db. The 'can't convert SQLite3::Statement into Array' error appears even if I do a db:drop before running db:migrate. I've tried updating rake and deleting rspec from my Gemfile but neither worked for me.

```
rake db:migrate -t
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)   
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env 
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
   rake aborted!
   can't convert SQLite3::Statement into Array
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:30:in `zip'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:30:in    `hash_rows'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:29:in `map'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:29:in `hash_rows'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:20:in `each'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord- 3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:315:in `map'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:315:in `tables'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:25:in  `table_exists?'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:417:in `initialize_schema_migrations_table'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `initialize'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:549:in `new'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:549:in `up'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:530:in `migrate'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:161
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
   /usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
   /usr/bin/rake:19
   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

the gems i'm using are:

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using multi_json (1.0.4) 
Using activesupport (3.1.1) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.1.1) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.3.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.0.3) 
Using actionpack (3.1.1) 
Using mime-types (1.17.2) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.3.0) 
Using actionmailer (3.1.1) 
Using arel (2.2.1) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.31) 
Using activerecord (3.1.1) 
Using activeresource (3.1.1) 
Using bundler (1.0.21) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.1.3) 
Using execjs (1.2.12) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.6.3) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.1.1) 
Using coffee-rails (3.1.1) 
Using jquery-rails (1.0.19) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.0) 
Using rails (3.1.1) 
Using sass (3.1.12) 
Using sass-rails (3.1.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.5) 
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5) 
Using uglifier (1.2.0) 
Using webrat (0.7.1)
```

Really confused about this error

Migration files:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.double :price
      t.string :category

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Using ruby 1.9.2 instead of 1.8.7 resulted in this:

```
    rake aborted!
    NoMethodError: undefined method `to_a' for #<SQLite3::Statement:0x007f9404b73b18>:
          SELECT name
          FROM sqlite_master
          WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'

    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: can you add your migration files ?

Answer (score 3):

the issue was resolved by modifying Gemfile to use:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

instead of

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

which was offered in the tutorial